# C++ 11 int8_t buggy input/output

Tags: c++11, input, printf, iostream, cstdint

This is a snipped of code from my program. I am using the `int8_t` data type, and I'm having some problems with input/output. Apparently, using `int8_t` in the program requires the `-std=c++11` flag to be set for the `g++` compiler. I did that, but there are runtime errors. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
int main() {
  int8_t number;

  cout << "Enter a number [1-100]: ";
  cin >> number;
  cout << "You entered: " << number << endl;
  cout << number << " / 10 = " << (number / 10) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of the program:

```
 $ ./a.out
Enter a number [1-100]: 95
You entered: 9
9 / 10 = 5
```

The `$` is the shell prompt. Anyway, it seems that only the first digit is read from the input stream. Even so, the integer division `9 / 10` should return `0`, not `5`. This program is intended to do `95 / 10` and return a result of `9`. Theoretically, this program should work, but apparently, even the division operator is buggy. I should make a note that using `int` instead of `int8_t` causes the program to work as intended. I suspect that in this case someone would just tell me to use the `int` data type and deal with it. But we are software engineers! I would like to know if the `int8_t` data type is inherently flawed. Why it can't accept proper user input, but also breaks the division operator?! Any programming language worth using must be free of such imperfections. And I think that C++ is popular enough that eventually someone realized that `int8_t` is flawed in some sense. That is something I need to know the intricacies of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the smallest type in C++ is `char`, and on most systems the last couple of decades that's equal to an 8-bit byte. So the type `int8_t` is usually an alias for `signed char`.

Second, when reading a `char` (`signed` or `unsigned`) from a stream with the `>>` operator, it reads a *character*. It doesn't matter if an alias type (like `int8_t`) is used, it's still a `char` type and will be read as a character.

So the result is that you read a single character, and the encoded value of that character is stored in your variable `number`. With [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) (the most common character encoding these days) the variable `number` will store the integer value `57` (ASCII for the character `'9'`) which divided by `10` is equal to the integer `5`.

If you want to read a small integer, use `int` for the type. If you want to store it in a byte (using `int8_t`) you have to either use temporary `int` variables, or cast the variable to an `int`. This casting have to be done for the printing as well (since otherwise the `char` overload of the `<<` operator will be used) so I recommend using plain `int` types for any integers by default.

Using smaller types than `int` is only relevant if you read/write raw binary data, or you're on a very small embedded system where every single byte (or maybe even *bit*) counts.

Answer (score 0):

So reflecting on Some programmer dude's post, I would like to add my own impressions. It seems that since `int8_t` is an alias to a `char`, `cout` and `cin` automatically treat the variable as a `char`, and do *character* input/output. I figured out a way to get around this, and actually do *integer* user input/output on the variable. It's simple. I use the C programming language functions `printf()` and `scanf()` to do the job. These functions have  format specifiers that allow you to treat the variable as being of any data type. Whereas `cout` and `cin` automatically interpret the data type, you can do it manually for `printf()` and `scanf()`, and that gives you a certain degree of power. Now my code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>  // you need this for printf() and scanf()
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
int main() {
  int8_t number;

  cout << "Enter a number [1-100]: ";
  // %hhd allows you to treat int8_t as an integer data type, instead of
  // a character
  scanf("%hhd", &number);
  printf("You entered: %hhd\n", number);
  printf("%hhd / 10 = %hhd\n", number, (number / 10));

  return 0;
}
```

And the actual output looks like this:

```
$ ./a.out
Enter a number [1-100]: 95
You entered: 95
95 / 10 = 9
```

It's a hack but it works! Well, you learn something new every single day.

---

Editing this answer, I would like to add some relevant links to related questions for those of you who want to do some more research.

[Are int8_t and uint8_t intended to be char types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911714/are-int8-t-and-uint8-t-intended-to-be-char-types/16002781)

[Difference between int32, int, int32_t, int8 and int8_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515874/difference-between-int32-int-int32-t-int8-and-int8-t)