# Difference between __int32 vs int vs int32_t (again)

Tags: c++

The answers around the web ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515874/difference-between-int32-int-int32-t-int8-and-int8-t), [two](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/288968/what-does-the-t-in-int32-t-signify)) only tell parts of the story, and omit some details that I would love you to help me to clarify:

- int, by the C++ standard, must be >= 32 bits.
- Different compilers (implementations) can make `int` to allocate different amount of bits by default. So `Compiler A` can make `int` to allocate 50 bits (for example) when I declare integer.
- Also, different compilers may / may not use [bit padding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) for optimization
- `__int32` (Microsoft-specifc) and `int32_t` are here to solve the problem and:

  - Force compiler to allocate exactly 32 bits.
  - Never use [bit padding before / after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58435348/what-is-bit-padding-or-padding-bits-exactly) this data type.

Which one of my guesses are correct? Sorry to reasking old question, but I am actally confused in all of that allocation features.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: ["__int32 is synonymous with type int"](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/cpp/int8-int16-int32-int64?view=vs-2019)

Comment: As far as I know the C++ standard does not require int to be at least 32 bits. https://stackoverflow.com/a/589684/920069

Comment: `int` has at least 16 bits granted by standard. The actual size depends on platform/compiler. ([cppreference.com - Fundamental types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Integer_types)). `int32_t` has granted 32 bits but is only defined when the platform provides a suitable integral type. ([cppreference.com - Fixed width integer types (since C++11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer))

Comment: your first link to bit padding links to a page that is not about bit padding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Which one of my guesses are correct?

> - int, by the C++ standard, must be >= 32 bits.

Not correct. `int` must be >= 16 bits. `long` must be >= 32 bits.

> Different compilers (implementations) can make int to allocate different amount of bits

Correct.

> ... by default.

I don't know of a compiler with configurable int sizes - it usually depends directly on target architecture - but I suppose that would be a possibility.

> Also, different compilers may / may not use bit padding

They may. They aren't required to.

> __int32 (Microsoft-specifc) and int32_t are here to solve the problem and:
>
> - Force compiler to allocate exactly 32 bits.
> - Never use bit padding before / after this data type.

Correct. More specifically, `std::int32_t` is an alias of one of the fundamental types which has exactly 32 bits and no padding. If such integer type is not provided by the compiler, then `std::int32_t` alias will not be provided either.

Microsoft documentation promises that `__int32` exists and that it is another name of `int`, and that it has 32 non-padding bits. Elsewhere, Microsoft documents that `int32_t` is also an alias of `int`. As such, there is no difference other than `__int32` not being a standard name.